# How can I call a Twilio Function from outside of Twilio?

Tags: twilio

I can't seem to be able to invoke a Twilio Function from outside of Twilio (e.g. curl, postman, browser, code, ...).

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Under the *Access Control* section of your Twilio Function, you could have your Function check for a valid Twilio signature before responding, which is useful for making webhooks with Twilio Functions. If you're calling your Twilio Function directly from a mobile app ([from an iOS app](https://www.twilio.com/blog/call-twilio-functions-from-ios-in-swift) or [Android](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/tutorials/how-to-call-twilio-functions-android), or in most cases (like I'm guessing in yours), the inbound HTTP request is not signed by Twilio so that checkbox can be left unchecked.

Protected Functions expect a valid Twilio signature. You can read more about [validating requests and valid Twilio signatures here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests).

A curl request should work if that checkbox is unchecked: `curl https://rosewood-starling-9398.twil.io/swift` returns [image]

You could also try a verbose curl request: `curl -v curl https://rosewood-starling-9398.twil.io/swift`. With the checkbox checked, it would return [image]. With the checkbox unchecked, you will see [image]

The verbose result has details like status code (here, it's 200, showing that the HTTP request was successful), Content Type (this response is JSON), Content Length (size of the response, which here, is 64 bytes), and more. The verbose flag (`-v`) can be used to get a better idea of what happened during the HTTP request.

Let me know if this helps at all! <3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make sure you uncheck signature validation on your Twilio Function which checks for a specific header signature which is signed by your authentication token

Alan