# Use curl to trigger twilio serverless function for testing

Tags: twilio

New to Twilio and I've got some serverless functions developed using the console ui. I have created them into the new Services framework (not classic).

I want to use curl to trigger these functions so that I can debug them using the "Live Logging" feature.

Searching on the internet yields confusing results - mixing up the "classic" and newer "services based" models.

The API docs state:

> Functions and Assets created by the API are not reflected in the Classic UI for those products. You cannot use the API to read Functions or Assets created with the Classic UI. The two systems are separate.

So using the services api seems to be out.

I have also seen mention of the need for an authentication header, and I can't see any guidance for how to generate that without programming using the helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

The magic key phrase that you're looking for is the ["Request Signature"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests). It basically means, the entire request, incl the parameters, needs to be signed and you can find more details [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141664/how-can-i-call-a-twilio-function-from-outside-of-twilio).

I understand that you asked for cURL instructions and it is possible to do in cURL, but I would recommend using this [Twilio CLI plugin](https://www.twilio.com/blog/validate-webhooks-with-new-webhook-plugin-for-twilio-cli) instead:

```bash
twilio plugins:install @twilio-labs/plugin-webhook

twilio webhook:invoke <YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL> \
  -d Body="Hi, how are you doing?" -d FromCountry=CA

twilio webhook:invoke https://ui-function-demo.twil.io/protected \
  -X POST --account-sid ACXXXXXXXXXXX \
  -X --auth-token abcdef
```

Comment: IOBert: I read the link that you shared that had curl examples but still am not understanding how to generate the request signature without setting up a node installation.

Comment: The links were meant to explain how the signature works and can be validated. What you try to do, is creating the signature. And for this, I'd strongly recommend using the webhooks plugin. I'm sure you could build this on your own, but I don't have the right resources to point you to.